# PHP Code Injection vulnerability exists even after recommended hardening

Tags: php, joomla3.0, websecurity

Using Burp to intercept traffic and inject code we have identified remote code execution vulnerability in a website
After entering data in input fields on the form and clicking submit the traffic was intercepted and the following commands were added to the request in the value of the input fields
%27%2bsystem(%22id%22)%2b%27
To fix it we have done the recommended hardening
1. On all the input fields we have done the input sanitization
We we have allowed only digits and put a limit on the number of digits allowed.
We have also used the functions such as htmlspecialchars , escapeshellcmd, escapeshellargs etc.

### This did not help.

2. So when we were able to intercept traffic and inject system command we checked the userid and removed shell access for this userid
   In etc/passwd it was /bin/bash for this user, we removed the access and verified that it was updated to /bin/false for this user

   ### This also did not help
3. The user whose id was displayed using code injection is the owner of the website home directory. We didn't try changing the ownership but We tried removing execute permissions for this user on the home directory,
   but then the site itself became inaccessible and was giving 403 forbidden error.

   ### So the execute permissions for this user and other users in the same group was retained
4. We have used disable_functions in php.ini to disable most of the recommended functions such as exec,system etc
   Restarted httpd , I was hopeful that this would solve the issue, but still the issue exists
   We have also used other directives such as Session cookie secure,Cookie httponly,session.referer_check,session.use_strict_mode etc. but all in vain

---

5. We are now planning to try removing the execute permission on /usr/bin for all users other than root.

   ### Is this a good thing to do, will this restrict the system commands being executed by the website owner-user

Could you please let me know if there is anything else that I can try ?

Comment: We are already using the close to latest php version - 7.1.25

Comment: This doesn't sound like a PHP question. I would defer you to https://security.stackexchange.com/ or https://serverfault.com/ The `input sanitization` Although perhaps it is a PHP question and you haven't shown the code that is related.. `functions such as` sounds like you are using multiple functions at once, if that is the case that is an issue. Each function should only be used for its specific use case.

Comment: Have you tried using parameterized queries?